# Create a Boxplot using ggplot showing a visualization from two data frames

Tags: r, ggplot2

Basically I have the following tables

Ost_Data which looks kind of like this

| Stadt | Langzeitarbeitslose |
| --- | --- |
| Hamburg | 33 |
| Koln | 21 |

and West_Data which looks like this

| Stadt | Langzeitarbeitslose |
| --- | --- |
| Berlin | 34 |
| Frankfurt | 55 |

now I want to plot them in a ggplot Boxplot where the x axis shows the 2 different data tables

```
 Ost_Data
```

and

```
West_data
```

and where on the y-axis the

```
Langzeitarbeitslose
```

is shown.

Essentially I want to compare the

```
Langzeitarbeitslose
```

value from each table against eachother

I tried

```
ggplot(data = Ost_data, West_data) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = ??, y = Langzeitarbeitslose)) + 
  labs(x = "Ost und Westdeutschland", y = "Langzeitarbeitslosenquote")
```

But that doesnt work as I don't specify that I need both tables and because I only Want to show the 2 Table names being Ost_data and West_data on the X-Axis and not a value out of the data tables.

This is how it should look like in general, even though the values here are wrong. On the X-axis I only want the naes of Ost_data and West_data and on the Y-Axis the actual values of `Langzeitarbeitslose`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to add an identifier to your datasets and row bind them which could be achieved in one step using e.g. `dplyr::bind_rows`. The identifier column could then be mapped on `x`:

```r
Ost_data <- data.frame(
  Stadt = c("Hamburg", "Koln"),
  Langzeitarbeitslose = c(33L, 21L)
)

West_data <- data.frame(
  Stadt = c("Berlin", "Frankfurt"),
  Langzeitarbeitslose = c(34L, 55L)
)

library(ggplot2)

dat <- dplyr::bind_rows(list(Ost = Ost_data, West = West_data), .id = "id")

ggplot(data = dat) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = id, y = Langzeitarbeitslose)) +
  labs(x = "Ost und Westdeutschland", y = "Langzeitarbeitslosenquote")
```

[image]